# Using list(string) from KeyVault through json loaded in dynamic block terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-rm

I'm loading json from Azure KeyVault and convert with `jsondecode()`.
While raw string is working, when I load the same string from KeyVault I cannot use it in `dynamic` Block.

**Error: Invalid dynamic for_each value
Cannot use a tuple value in for_each. An iterable collection is required.**

**Working**

```
resource "azurerm_monitor_action_group" "SIDevelopment" {
  name                = "Test"
  resource_group_name = "kv-test"
  short_name          = "Test"

  dynamic "email_receiver" {
    for_each = jsondecode("[\"example1@email.com\",\"example2@email.com\"]")
    content {
      name                    = email_receiver.value
      email_address           = email_receiver.value
      use_common_alert_schema = false
    }
  }
}
```

**Not Working**

```
data "azurerm_key_vault" "this" {
  name                = var.key_vault_name
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
}

data "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "secret" {
  name         = var.secret_name
  key_vault_id = data.azurerm_key_vault.this.id
}

resource "azurerm_monitor_action_group" "SIDevelopment" {
  name                = "Test"
  resource_group_name = "kv-test"
  short_name          = "Test"

  dynamic "email_receiver" {
    for_each = jsondecode(data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.secret.value)
    content {
      name                    = email_receiver.value
      email_address           = email_receiver.value
      use_common_alert_schema = false
    }
  }
}
```

When I try to compare results they are looks equal

```
output "kv"{
  value = jsondecode(data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.secret.value)
  sensitive = true
}

output "string"{
  value = jsondecode("[\"example1@email.com\",\"example2@email.com\"]")
  sensitive = true
}
```

after read output as json

```json
{
  "kv": {
    "sensitive": true,
    "type": [
      "tuple",
      [
        "string",
        "string"
      ]
    ],
    "value": [
      "example1@email.com",
      "example2@email.com"
    ]
  },
  "string": {
    "sensitive": true,
    "type": [
      "tuple",
      [
        "string",
        "string"
      ]
    ],
    "value": [
      "example1@email.com",
      "example2@email.com"
    ]
  }
}
```

I've try toset, tolist, etc.
And still can't figure out why string from KeyVault behave differently.

Comment: Did you Try using count instead of for_each? @Uriu

Comment: @VinayB can you please show some example how you want to use count in dynamic block?

Comment: So once please confirm that your request is to create an email receiver in the Azure Monitor Action Group for each email address in the list stored in the secret present in the vault.  Does this match your requirements? @Uiru

Comment: @VinayB yes, thats what I try to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's was just a missing `nonsensitive` function

for_each = jsondecode(**nonsensitive**(data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.secret.value))

So to make it work it I've replace code to be like this

```
resource "azurerm_monitor_action_group" "SIDevelopment" {
  name                = "Test"
  resource_group_name = "kv-test"
  short_name          = "Test"

  dynamic "email_receiver" {
    for_each = jsondecode(nonsensitive(data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.secret.value))
    content {
      name                    = email_receiver.value
      email_address           = email_receiver.value
      use_common_alert_schema = false
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

> I tried to create an email receiver in the Azure Monitor Action Group for each email address in the list stored in the secret present in the vault using count instead of dynamic foreach and I was able to provision the requirement successfully.

It seems that your scenario does not support using `for_each` with an object (map) that is derived from a list. This is uncommon, as usually this conversion from a list to a map with indices as keys should be successful. However, there may be some particularities in your situation that trigger this problem.

For this case I suggest`count` is a better choice than `dynamic foreach` for your task of looping through a simple list of email addresses. `count` is easy to use for lists that have a fixed order and don't require individual labels for each item.

Before you configure anything, verify that the JSON data in the Azure Key Vault consists of a list of email addresses in this format: `["email1@example.com", "email2@example.com", ...]`.

**My demo terraform configuration:**

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

variable "key_vault_name" {
  description = "The name of the key vault"
  type        = string
}

variable "resource_group_name" {
  description = "The name of the resource group"
  type        = string
}

variable "secret_name" {
  description = "The name of the secret in the key vault"
  type        = string
}

data "azurerm_key_vault" "this" {
  name                = var.key_vault_name
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
}

data "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "secret" {
  name         = var.secret_name
  key_vault_id = data.azurerm_key_vault.this.id
}

resource "azurerm_monitor_action_group" "SIDevelopment" {
  name                = "Test"
  resource_group_name = "demorg-vk"
  short_name          = "Test"


  count = length(jsondecode(data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.secret.value))

  email_receiver {
    name                    = "emailReceiver-${count.index}"
    email_address           = jsondecode(data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.secret.value)[count.index]
    use_common_alert_schema = false
  }
}



output "kv" {
  value     = tolist(jsondecode(data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.secret.value))
  sensitive = true
}

output "string" {
  value     = jsondecode("[\"example1@email.com\",\"example2@email.com\"]")
  sensitive = true
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: thanks for suggestion,
But this is not going to solve my problem.
Your example is going to create only one email receiver with one email receiver
Where I want to create multiple emails receivers base on list from keyVault, that's why I'm using dynamic block here.

base on my observation I suspect there is some problem with encoding while using secret value directly from keyVault secret.

If I try to save secret in file and then read it from file it will be working.

Comment: I tried this "Try to save the secret in a file and then read it from the file it will work" however it doesn't not satisfy the condition of dynamic property.